# UIButton within UITableViewCell issue: can't get recognized selector

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

So I've been searching StackExchange on how to put a UIButton inside of a UITableViewCell and thought I found the answer, but keep getting an `"unrecognized selector sent to instance"` error.

Here's where I call the function

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tblTeams.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellReuse")! as! TeamsTableViewCell

    cell.btnLeave.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.btnLeave.addTarget(self, action: "LeaveTeam:", for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

    return cell
}
```

and here's where the function is. It's within the same class, and even extension, as the prior code block

```
@IBAction func LeaveTeam(sender: UIButton){
}
```

I've tried rewording the quote, I've tried using `#selector`... just please tell me how I do it right. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
cell.btnLeave.addTarget(self, action: #selector(leaveTeam(_:)) for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
```

---

```
@objc func leaveTeam(_ sender: UIButton) {---}
```

start method name in lower case

Comment: I still get "unrecognized selector". Is there any extra information I could give you?

Answer (score 0):

```
addTarget(self, action:#selector(leaveTeam(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

@objc func leaveTeam(sender : UIButton) -> Void {

    }
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.